# Algorithm to calculate path of vector field line between two charges

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, software

I have a program that can draw a line between two charges. However I need a function or basic algorithm in order to draw the correct line which is always tangential to the vector field.

This is not stack overflow but perhaps you can help by reminding me of some holy grail function that can govern my lines when I draw them.

Comment: -1. No research effort. Did you try googling your title? One hit on the first page is http://my.ece.ucsb.edu/York/Bobsclass/134/Handouts/FieldLines.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tangential lines are called the "field lines". If you know the vector field, then you know the direction of the tangent line at every point. It is $\frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|}$. Given this, you can make small steps in the direction of the field at every point, calculating the new direction of the step at each point.